# What is the faster way to load callback from class in laravel route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

```
 1. Route::get('list', [App\Http\Controllers\Driver\DocumentController::class,'list']);
 2. Route::get('list', ['Driver\DocumentController@list']);
```

What is the faster way to load callback from class in laravel route ?

I am writting REST API. I need high performance solution

Comment: Neither of these are faster or slower than the other... The 1st one is the current syntax, the 2nd one is the old syntax, but both are still valid and do the same thing, which is associate your `/list` URL with your `DocumentController`'s `public function list()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **it does not matter<sup>(*)</sup>**. You should cache things as part of your build script (`php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan view:cache` and `php artisan route:cache`).

When you cache the routes, a file is created, in `bootstrap/cache/routes-v7.php` if I'm not mistaken. When the routes are cached, your `routes/web.php` and `routes/api.php` files will simply be ignored.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> you *should* use the newer syntax still.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are the same in performance. The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files) recommends defining your routes in an array format and [using action verbs.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) (`index` instead of `list`)

```
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```